# adding dependencies generates multidex issue

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

i am using this example dependencies

```
compile ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.8.5@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
```

Link:-  https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since December 3rd, 2014, build tools 1.0.0-rc1 was released. Now, all you need to do is override this in your Application class:

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
and modify your build.gradle like so:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

For more info, this is a [good guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Answer (score 2):

Add multidex true in your gradle defaultConfig.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ... 
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' //update accordingly
   }
```